# AttributeError: 'AtlasView' object has no attribute 'nodes'

Tags: numpy, networkx, pickle

I am creating a graph from a pickled file. However, when I executed the for loop, the following error shows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 150, in 
> main()
> File "main.py", line 30, in main
> graphs = read_graphs(FLAGS.input_file)
> File "F:GAWD\utils.py", line 33, in read_graphs
> for n in g.nodes():

The following is the code snippent:

```
class Graph(object):
def __init__(self,
             gid=VACANT_GRAPH_ID,
             eid_auto_increment=True):
    self.gid = gid
    self.vertices = dict()
    self.edges = dict()
    self.eid_auto_increment = eid_auto_increment
    self.counter = itertools.count()

with open(file_name, 'rb') as handle:
    data = np.array([g[0] for g in pickle.load(handle)],dtype=object)

graphs = dict()
for idx, g in enumerate(data):  
    tgraph = Graph(idx, eid_auto_increment=True)
    for n in g.nodes():  # the error occurs here
        tgraph.add_vertex(int(n), str(g.nodes[n]['type']))
    for e in g.edges():
        tgraph.add_edge(AUTO_EDGE_ID, int(e[0]), int(e[1]), 1, 
    int(g.edges[e]['weight']))
    graphs[idx] = tgraph
```

Any help or comment would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Couple comments: 1) to give a good answer, we'll need to see the full error message (e.g., line number etc).  Since I don't know where the error is, I can't diagnose this.  2) It's not clear that anything here is using networkx.  Is it?

Comment: No, this error actually has nothing to do with Networkx. The error is in the for loop line. Specially, g.nodes() in undefiened. The code tried to create a numpy array to represent a graph from a pickled file. @joel

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the full error message?

Comment: I did. I hope it clarifies everything. The code snippet is from read_graphs function in this repo: https://github.com/mengchillee/GAWD/blob/master/utils.py

Comment: Where's the data file from?  It appears that the pickled data is not in the format the code expects.

Comment: I’m using the same pickled file from the GitHub repository. It should work because that’s what the author of code is using. - #joel

Comment: You can use one of the files from the following url https://github.com/mengchillee/GAWD/tree/master/data/original